# Error updating compose.material3 from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I use `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1` but I want to use BottomSheets introduced in 1.1.0

But when I update version of material3 I'm starting to receive build errors like this:

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.DirectoryEntriesReader found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)
```

I'm using 1.3.3 version of `androidx.compose.ui:*` and tried to update to 1.4.3 but nothing changed.

I'm using 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' and tried to update it to '1.8.0' but got build errors:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
```

Other plugin versions:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem.

The solution could be excessive, but it works, which is fine for me for now.

### What I did to solve the problem:

#### 1. Two kotlin plugins

I had used two similar plugins in each project module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

So I've removed one:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

#### 2. Java version

I've updated all java versions to 17 in each project module

```
    def javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        android {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = javaVersion.toString()
            }

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility javaVersion
                targetCompatibility javaVersion
            }
        }

        java {
            sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
            targetCompatibility = javaVersion
        }
```

#### 3. kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion

I've updated kotlin commiler version in all project modules:

```
            composeOptions {
                kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion composeKotlinCompilerVersion
            }
```

#### 4. Compose versions

`compose-ui` version was updated to `1.4.3`

`compose-material3` version was set from `1.0.1` to `1.1.0`

---

All this works with version catalog without BOM. Probably will try to use BOM later.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know which library is out of sync exactly...

If you're interested in getting everything up to date and in sync you could consider using the compose BOM instead of individual versions for each library:

```
val composeBom = platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.05.01")
implementation(composeBom)

implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to do so. This gives the same errors.